# Android GoogleMaps NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, google-maps-api-2

I get the following frustrating error.

```
02-15 16:13:12.562: W/dalvikvm(2637): VFY: unable to resolve static field 740 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
02-15 16:13:12.562: D/dalvikvm(2637): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
02-15 16:13:12.566: D/AndroidRuntime(2637): Shutting down VM
02-15 16:13:12.566: W/dalvikvm(2637): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41506300)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.test.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-15 16:13:12.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

All I did was following the get started guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: wrong import. check your imports

Comment: Try extends MapActivity instead of extends Activity

Comment: added import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; //same
//it's caused by fragment in layout xml

Comment: extending MapActivity doesn't work. "missing element MapActivity"

Comment: MapActivity is part of Google Maps V1, you should just extend FragmentActivity